# apt-install keep failing due to previous package installation failure

Tags: dpkg

I am trying to install a package A. previously, i tried to install a very different package B during which dpkg failed. I did `dpkg --congiure -a` after that and now I am stuck because every time I try to install a new package, dpkg still tries to instll package B, which always fails.

How do I tell dpkg to ignore package B that was previously attmeted?

Comment: You need to fix the prior installation fails first. Read your messages for your *unstated* release, as they provide clues; be the problem lack of disk space, package source issue or otherwise.

Comment: Can you edit the question and post the whole error message?